# ElasticSearch - Sort on the subaggregation

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, bucket-sort

I am quite new to elasticsearch, I am trying to sort on a subaggregations. that is my results should be sorted based on the sub aggregations first. I have tried lot of things to enable this sort but it isn't working. Can anyone help with this?

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_part": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "part",
        "size": 1000
      }
    },
      "aggs": {
    "distinct_manufacturer": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "manufacturer",
        "size": 1000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to sort on the manufacturer, my entire result should be sorted on that? Can someone point me on how I can achieve that?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Answer (score 2):

I tried to do a test locally with your query. I did a small correction if I understood your issue well. I ingested the following data in the index "subsorting":

```
  "part": "car",
  "manufacturer": "brandA"

  "part": "car",
  "manufacturer": "brandB"

  "part": "car",
  "manufacturer": "brandC"

  "part": "motor",
  "manufacturer": "brandA"

  "part": "motor",
  "manufacturer": "brandB"

  "part": "motor",
  "manufacturer": "brandC"
```

Note: Both part and manufacturer are mapped as text.

```
GET subsorting/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_part": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "part.keyword",
        "size": 1000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "distinct_manufacturer": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "manufacturer.keyword",
            "order": {
              "_key": "asc"
            }, 
            "size": 1000
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If both fields "part" and "manufacturer" are mapped as keywords, remove the ".keywords" from the query.

The response from the above query is as follows if sorted as ascending order:

```
"aggregations" : {
  "distinct_part" : {
    "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
    "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
    "buckets" : [
      {
        "key" : "motor",
        "doc_count" : 4,
        "distinct_manufacturer" : {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
          "buckets" : [
            {
              "key" : "brandA",
              "doc_count" : 2
            },
            {
              "key" : "brandB",
              "doc_count" : 1
            },
            {
              "key" : "brandC",
              "doc_count" : 1
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "key" : "car",
        "doc_count" : 3,
        "distinct_manufacturer" : {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
          "buckets" : [
            {
              "key" : "brandA",
              "doc_count" : 1
            },
            {
              "key" : "brandB",
              "doc_count" : 1
            },
            {
              "key" : "brandC",
              "doc_count" : 1
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If you need the result as descending order, here is the response where `"_key": "desc"`:

```
"aggregations" : {
  "distinct_part" : {
    "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
    "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
    "buckets" : [
      {
        "key" : "motor",
        "doc_count" : 4,
        "distinct_manufacturer" : {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
          "buckets" : [
            {
              "key" : "brandC",
              "doc_count" : 1
            },
            {
              "key" : "brandB",
              "doc_count" : 1
            },
            {
              "key" : "brandA",
              "doc_count" : 2
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "key" : "car",
        "doc_count" : 3,
        "distinct_manufacturer" : {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
          "buckets" : [
            {
              "key" : "brandC",
              "doc_count" : 1
            },
            {
              "key" : "brandB",
              "doc_count" : 1
            },
            {
              "key" : "brandA",
              "doc_count" : 1
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Links:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html